# CreateProcess error=5

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

After update android' soft for develop I had a little problem in some projects in eclipse, but yesterday I opened my project in IDEA and I get an error that java had a different class path `bin/java` rather `bin/` I fixed it, but then I have an error  `CreateProcess error=5`, I know  that its mean in ProgramFiles/Java folder is read-only permission, but what have I do to solve this one? Maybe I should downgrade Java or update IDEA, or give more permissions?

Comment: Did you try IDEA 12.1.4? Try deleting JDK/Android SDK platforms and add them again.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2, now problem only with JDK I will try to reinstall it

Comment: IDEA 11.1.2 will not work with the latest Android SDK. You need 12.1.4.